# How can I process a Response directly in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, response, httpresponse

I'm writing code in my Laravel Controller and I want to trap some exceptions firing a response directly without returning something to the routes.

For example, I wrote a method for returning a 404 response:

```
public static function respondNotFound( $message = null, $instantResponse = false )
{
    $message = $message ? $message : "Not Found";
    $statusCode = self::STATUS_NOTFOUND;
    return self::makeResponse( array( 'status' => $statusCode, 'message' => $message ), $statusCode );
}
```

This method calls another one for building an Illuminate Response

```
protected static function makeResponse( $data, $statusCode = self::STATUS_OK, $instantResponse = false )
{
    $response = Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response::json( $data, $statusCode );
    $response->setCallback( Input::get( 'callback' ) );
    if( $instantResponse ) {
                //..... I want to fire my Response here!
    }
    else {
        return $response;
    }

}
```

Referring to the method above, I want to specify that my response must be fired directly rather than being returned outside, avoiding a "waterfall of return".

My solution is to set up some php headers and then kill the script, but I think that it's a bit rough.

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$response->setCallback` is to add a callback for `jsonP` request, are you trying to print the response ?

Comment: Sure! I prepare my response for a JsonP output (just if the callback parameter is specified).

Comment: What did you mean by `I want to fire my Response here!` ? Explain `fire` please, do you want to print it/ send to the client ?

Comment: Yes, I want to print out my response directly

Comment: Just return it, `Laravel` will it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused - why dont you just use the `App::missing()` filter and handle your 404 in there?

In 'app/start/global.php' add:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
 {
    if (Request::ajax())
    {
        return Response::json( ['status' => 'error', 'msg' => 'There was an error. I could not find what you were looking for.'] );
    }
    elseif ( ! Config::get('app.debug')) 
    {
        return Response::view('errors.404', array(), 404);
    }
 });
```

From looking at your code - you seem to be duplicating the response class. I dont understand why you are doing all of that, when you can just do

```
 return Response::view('error', $message, $statuscode);
```

anywhere in your application...

Edit: you could also do

```
App::abort(404);
```

And then catch the abort filter in your app. You can change the 404 to be any HTTP response code you want.

Comment: Your example is great, but I wish to fire different status codes with different messages...